# How Hadoop put together the program and data?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new the Hadoop. I have been reading documents about Hadoop but always puzzled by this question. How does Hadoop related the program and the data. Hadoop puts the data in the HDFS, and creates copies. Does the user have any control on which node save which data? (Does the user need to care about this even if he/she can?) When a mapreduce program starts, how does Hadoop put together the program and the data? It should try to avoid any unnecessary data transfer between the nodes. So does it load the program (say, the mapper) to the node that contains the data? If this is the case, what if the input data for one mapper is so large such that it is stored on multiple nodes? Does Hadoop smartly to the mapper on all these nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, the user has no real control over that where the data is stored.
2. No, the user should not care either.
3. Hadoop picks the datanodes closest to the mapper, in the order of localhost -> same rack -> data center.
4. Yes, it **tries** to get data from localhost first.
5. It depends, you should read up on what an "input split" and an "HDFS block" mean. A single file on HDFS could be split over several HDFS blocks and therefore reside on multiple datanodes. A mapper's inputs are by definition **independant of each other**, therefore, even if the file gets split in the middle and several mappers take portions of it (assuming, e.g., it's split at a line break), the progam should produce the same output. Hadoop tries to get a data *block* that's close to the mapper's location, and this could mean a file or a part of it. Due to HDFS being replicated, blocks from a multitude of different files could reside on the mapper's datanode, so it has a pretty good selection available.
6. See bullet 5., but pretty much yes -- Hadoop runs mapper's "close" to the data, or at least tries to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful! So what is the minimum unit of data to put into a mapper? It seems to me it is not a file (a file could across multiple nodes), but a HDFS block? But if this is the case, how can we guarantee that the blocks chopped by HDFS is still usable by the mappers? If it is split at a line break, I can imagine that it will work. But what is the general way of splitting?

Comment: @szli That is typically the job of a particular input format. It gets info about the nodes and the particular parts of the file that reside on those nodes from the namenode and then decides how to assign input splits. Everything I've said in the answer generally holds for built-in `InputFormat`s, i.e., a `TextInputFormat` will split the file at a newline for you.

Comment: (1) User can control this now(Hadoop 1.2.0 onward), (2) If the user thinks his/her data is too too important, he/she should definitely care about that. For instance, what happens if the datacenter catches fire.

Comment: @Tariq Thanks, I'll look into it. Haven't followed the newest alphas / betas lately. :) For sure can't be done on 1.0.4 stable.

Comment: You are welcome TC1 :)..just to keep szli up to date.

Comment: @TC1 I see. Then what happens if my file is not txt? Does Hadoop allow user to define a split rule so that any block of the file can be fed to the mapper?

Comment: Yes. The split creation is done by the logic written into the getSplits() of the InputFormat you are using.

Comment: @szli To add to Tariq, you can get the particular datanodes hosting each particular blocks in the `InputFormat`, but you seem like you're new to Hadoop so I didn't want to overwhelm you. If you use the built-in formats, like `SequenceInputFormat` etc., they take care of that. You can implement your own from scratch if you want, but it gets messy.

Comment: just to add to that, the getSplits() decides how a particular file is gonna get chopped into pieces(Splits). it is one of the methods present in the InputFormat class you are using. in case of TextInputFormat(the default), it is splitting by "\n". but you could always define it in the you wish. the split created by getSplits() is the minimum unit of data that is given to a mapper for processing.

Comment: i totally agree with TC1. you must read the Chapter 7 from the book "Hadoop-Definitive Guide" by Tom White. i think it is the best place to start with, especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Few cents from my side :
1- The relation between data and program implies that the processing takes place on the machine where the data to be processed is present(except for a couple of exceptional cases).

2- As per the default behavior a user doesn't have the control(also doesn't have to worry about) over the block placement. It's done automatically by an algorithm embedded in the NameNode's code, referred to as "Block Placement Policy". But, if you are not satisfied with the default block placement and are of adventurous nature you could definitely play with the Block Placement Policy(Hadoop 1.2.0 onwards). For a detailed info on this you could visit this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-385)

3- Hadoop tries its best to avoid data movement and it does so by starting the mappers on the machines where data is already present. But there are a few exceptions to that, as I have mentioned in the first point. If the block of data(called as a Split) which a mapper has to process is bigger than the HDFS block size, the remaining part of that Split is moved from one node to the other node where mapper is supposed to run(This answers your second last question as well).

4- The second scenario, when data movement occurs, arises when the machine having the data to be processed has no free CPU slots to start the mapper. In such a case instead of waiting unnecessarily, the data block is moved to a nearby node where free mapper slots are available(But these 2 situations occur rarely).

The MapReduce framework tries its best to maintain data locality and to make the computation as efficient as possible.